# R: calling function on multiple list entries

Tags: r, optimization, for-loop

I'm really new to R but have a computer science background. I currently am trying to read in a bunch of different data files and then perform some analysis (the same) on each of them.

Right now, I have a list of datasets. So, my first data set is in list[[1]], second in list[[2]], etc. So, what I was going to do is loop on the length of the list and call some function passing values from two columns into that function from each unique dataset. I was reading an article on this, however, and found that:

```
foo = seq(1, 100, by=2)
foo.squared = NULL
foo.squared = foo^2
```

will square all the values within foo. So, is there any way to do something similar for my case? For example, passing in values from all the datasets in the list or something?

To make this more concrete, I have a list of datasets named data_list and each data set is identical with columns a, b and c. I need to call a function f with the arguments a and b from the datasets. Is there any way to do this besides using a for loop?

Please let me know if that makes sense. Sorry for any confusion, like I said, I am very new to this language. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `?lapply` is what you're after

Comment: You don't need the `foo.squared = NULL` in your code

Comment: Generally speaking - no, you'll need to loop - with either a `for` or one of the `apply` family functions, but very frequently for a specific function there will be a shortcut, so if you want good answers - be specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
lapply(data_list, function(x) f(x$a, x$b))
```